# Android white view appearing before keyboard in the dark theme on React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-layout, keyboard

On Android in the dark theme after the tap to TextInput field before the keyboard appear the whit view for a few second. On IOS it works fine, without any troubles. Already tried to change the behavior property, but it did not help me. I have found the information about the same bug, but on the previous early versions of React Native. My is 0.63.2. Can somebody recommend how to solve it please.
[image]